# MS SQL Login failed for user 'sa'.[CLIENT: <local machine>]

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I changed the password of sa using the command [ALTER LOGIN WITH PASSWORD]. Then , it keeps showing the below message in fail log every minute.
Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided.[CLIENT: ]
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

> How can I fix it?

You'll need to look at where the client is attempting the connection and change the password to the correct one, if you want that client to continue working. Otherwise, stop the application or service that is attempting the connections.